# How do I use the Euler-Maclaurin Summation to find the zeros of the Riemann-Zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta, euler-maclaurin

I read [this paper](http://www.phys.uconn.edu/phys2400/downloads/euler-maclaurin-summation.pdf) which describes Euler-Maclaurin Summation as a method for evaluating sums in terms of an integral. I also read from [this Quora answer](https://qr.ae/TWhnV4) that Euler-Maclaurin summation is one method to find zeros on the critical strip.

However, it isn't obvious to me how to use this formula in order to find zeros. Can someone please explain it in terms a not-so-bright undergraduate can understand?

Comment: It is not obvious because it is not the method you are willing to use. The zeros on $\Re(s)=1/2$ are found from the functional equation saying $\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$ is real on $\Re(s)=1/2$ so it has a zero at each zero crossing. Hence, you need a formula for approximating $\zeta(s),\Gamma(s/2)$ on $\Re(s)=1/2$ (for example one based on $\eta(s)$) Then you'll need to use the argument principle to show there are no other zeros on $\Re(s) \in [-1,2], \Im(s) \in [-T,T]$, the same argument principle would be what you need to prove there is some offline zero near $\sigma+it$.

Comment: Concretely the EMSF is useful to estimate $\sum_{n=N}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ when $N$ is large enough.

Comment: @reuns I don't see the connection between that sum and the location of zeros on the critical line.

Comment: Of course the connection is that $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$. It remains to estimate $\Gamma(s/2)$ to evaluate $\Re(\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)), \Re(s) = 1/2$ and locate its zeros crossings.

Comment: @reuns But that definition of $\zeta$ is only good for $s = \sigma + it$ where $\sigma > 1$.